# ajax auto complete textbox is not working when 2 autocomplete texboxes are present in same page

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-ajax

I have a page where 180 items need to be searched for 1 text box and 200 items for 2nd textbox. Auto complete is working fine for 1st textbox and not giving auto complete option for 2nd textbox here is my code.

```
<td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TB_DeptID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender
                                               runat="server" 
                                               ID="AC_Dept" 
                                               TargetControlID="TB_DeptID"
                                               CompletionListElementID="divwidth"
                                               MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
                                               CompletionInterval="10"
                                               EnableCaching="true"
                                               CompletionSetCount="12"
                                               ServiceMethod="GetDept" ></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
            </td>

<td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TB_chargeHdId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:AutoCompleteExtender
                                               runat="server" 
                                               ID="CH_autocomplete" 
                                               TargetControlID="TB_chargeHdId"
                                               CompletionListElementID="divwidth"
                                               MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
                                               CompletionInterval="10"
                                               EnableCaching="true"
                                               CompletionSetCount="12"
                                               ServiceMethod="GetchrgHd_Id"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

            </td>
```

and in code behind

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetchrgHd_Id(string prefixText)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        // select custaddress1 from tblcustomer
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 Charge_Head_Id from Charge_Head_M where Charge_Head_Id like '" + prefixText + "'+'%'", con);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname_code", prefixText);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        List<string> custaddress1 = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            custaddress1.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Charge_Head_Id"].ToString());
        }
        return custaddress1;
    }

    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

    public static List<string> GetDept(string prefixText1)
    {

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        // select custaddress1 from tblcustomer
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 Dept_Id from Department_M where Dept_Id like '" + prefixText1 + "'+'%'", con);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemname_code", prefixText);
        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp1.Fill(dt1);
        List<string> custaddress2 = new List<string>();
        for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            custaddress2.Add(dt1.Rows[j]["Dept_Id"].ToString());
        }
        return custaddress2;
    }
```

how to resolve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `prefixtext1` to `prefixtext` in `getdept` method.